# What does the expression くそかわ mean?

Tags: slang, spoken-language

I read many times the expression くそかわ referred to babies, what does it exactly mean in English?

I know that くそ means "damn" while かわ comes from かわいい, right?

So *damn cute*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, right. くそ・クソ・糞 is used in place here for what usually would be すごく, e.g.

> くそかわ = すごく可愛い
> くそうめぇ = すごくうまい (=すごくおいしい)
> etc.

(As slang is usually more versatile, there are more expressions with クソ, where すごく isn't a valid substitution, e.g. 糞美人. Also, note that くそ isn't traditionally a positive interjection/prefix/etc., but traditionally used to embellish derogatory terms.)

I'm not 100% on the precise ordering, but クソ is probably the most recent of a series of similar expressions

> めっちゃうまい (from むちゃくちゃ)
> まじうまい (from 真面目)
> 超{ちょう}うまい
> 鬼{おに}うまい
> くそうまい

In any case, as you guessed, it is a stronger expression, just as in English:

> くそかわ "damn cute"
> すごくかわいい "really cute"

As you say, かわ is just a short form of かわいい, as common with all "i-adjectives", うまい => うま(っ), すごい => すご etc.

Comment: I guess くそ deserves its own answer on [this question](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1129/are-there-any-japanese-words-as-versatile-as-fuck-in-english).

Comment: In this case, 鬼 = "devilishly" perhaps?

Comment: You'd basically be looking for a word, which gets used the same way "damn(ed)" gets used, but isn't "damn(ed)". "f**king", "super", etc. work, but I don't think "devilishly" quite fits the bill. Maybe "as hell" as in "cute as hell"... Anyway, there's no need to translate it with the same metaphor.

Answer (score -2):

It means F**king cute.

It is commonly used by gals, but it can be a little rude so I will not recommend you to use it in public.

It is one of the gal language - for more informations on gal language visit http://injapan.gaijinpot.com/featured-photo/2011/09/14/japanese-gal-language-what-is-%E2%80%9Cagepoyo%E2%80%9D/