# What does ぴろーん mean?

Tags: meaning, slang, definitions, internet-slang

This appears to be some kind of adult slang term, or maybe it's internet slang, whatever the case may be I can't find a definition in any dictionary. Is it an onomatopoeia?

Comment: I know exactly what it means but I don't know whether or not it is ok to explain it here.

Comment: That's what I thought, because I even asked on Yahoo answers in Japan and no one's answering. There must be some way you can explain it without having to be explicit.

Comment: All I get so far is that it might have something to do with "penis" and it might have something to do with stretching, but it still isn't clear.

Comment: @TokyoNagoya:  Just explain it as objectively as possible.  After all, this topic exists.  http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1129/78

Comment: It's okay to discuss taboo language (although it's understandable if some users want to avoid doing so).  After all, taboo language is still language.  One caveat: we should try to keep question titles "safe for work" in case they're promoted on other Stack Exchange sites, which people may be using from work.  (The question istrasci links to would have to have its title censored if it were asked today.)

Answer (score 7):

It is an onomatopoeia, not the name for an object unless the author/speaker uses it as such for his own aesthetic purposes but this would be fairly rare.

It describes the way a long object dangles, stretches, lies down, etc. in a lazy manner.  The long object coud actually be anything from linguini to a cat stretching its body, from hair to stretching cheese, etc.

If OP saw/heard the word in adult content, it would probably be about a male organ.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. Does the first part, the "P," stand for an English word that also starts with "P," and is perhaps, 5 letters long?

Comment: Is it the second "P" in the women's version of O.P.P.?

Answer (score 2):

ぴろーん is an onomatopoeia to describe a long thin rolled object extends and runs like a tonge of a chameleon. It's nothing to do with adult slang terms.

Comment: I think user4092 is right. It has nothing to do with those mystic funny connotation.

Answer (score 0):

maybe its a "loooooong" penis?

Comment: That's what I would have guessed.

Comment: @istrasci なんでぇ～～ｗｗｗ