# What does ぺろん mean?

Tags: translation, manga, onomatopoeia

I'm trying to understand a scene from a manga which I'll describe as best as possible.
One person is undressing and there is an onomatopoeia that reads ぺろん. Another person says then:

> おい、ぺろんって私の身体で何してんの

Which I guess means something like

> Hey, what are you doing to my body?

I don't understand what ぺろん means here. Can't find it easily anywhere. Some meanings I've found [here](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%BA%E3%82%8D%E3%82%93/). Something similar in [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14424/what-does-%e3%81%b4%e3%82%8d%e3%83%bc%e3%82%93-mean) question. From that, I understand the onomatopoeia, it gives the idea of something dangling (in this case the clothes), but I still don't understand its meaning within that sentence.

Comment: Adding to Angelos' comment: ぺろぺろ is another related word.

Comment: @Angelos thank you. I still can't translate it into context (in the sentece, i mean). I have fixed the second link, which was faulty.

Comment: 私の身体で means more like "using my body" or "in my body", not "to my body" so it sounds like the two characters in question have maybe switched their bodies. Is that the case? Could you provide more context about the situation and the characters

Comment: @sigh indeed that was the case, the characters had their bodies switched. In the end I understood it as "Why are you undressing my body?" meaning "That body is mine, why are you the one undressing it".

Comment: @blundered_bishop Based on the sentence alone, I think it's more that the person who says it didn't like the *way* the other person undressed and less that they didn't want them to undress in the first place. My wild guess: they're a girl and a boy and the boy, in the girl's body, suddenly stripped naked as if *she* doesn't care about being seen in the nude, which the girl didn't like because it's her own body. But again, we need more information about the situation and their personalities to figure out what the sentence actually means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first definition in your link says 「舌を出す様子」, and links to ぺろり, which it defines as 「なめる様子」.

Basically, the setnence means something 'What are you doing, licking my body?'

Comment: I understand. This translation does not make sense in the context presented. [Here](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%BA%E3%82%8D%E3%82%8A) there seems to be another meaning: the act of peeling off something in one go/completely, which would be "undressing" in this context.

Comment: @blundered_bishop In that case, give us the actual context to see. Post an image or something.